# ICMP packets leave linux device with wrong IP source after VPN establishment

Tags: linux, networking, routes, vpn, ping

I’m using Linux 2.6.32 device that establishes a VPN connection. When VPN is up, all packets sent by the device, includes the VPN client src address.

ICMP packets continuously go through the VPN interface and successfully encrypted/decrypted, and after that they are sent to the WLAN via the WLAN interface (as ESP packet with the VPN Interface as src ip).

After disabling the VPN, the VPN interface goes down, ICMP packets are sent directly to the WLAN interface (with the WLAN Interface as src ip) in plaintext un-encrypted.
But when the VPN is established again and the VPN interface is up again, packets are sent at the same way, but the ESP packet encapsulates a WLAN src IP and not the VPN src IP.

ICMP packets go through the VPN interface and then via WLAN interface as ESP packet with the WLAN Interface as src ip and not VPN Interface as src ip.

The only way to have the ESP packets leave with the VPN IP address encapsulated is either:

- Wait until the machines "nf_conntrack_icmp_timeout" expires, and restart ping application.
- Remove the WLAN interface (ifconfig down) and set it up again (ifconfig up).

Both solutions are not appropriate, as I don’t want to stop the ping and I don’t want to reconfigure the device network interface.

I tried to clear the routing cache by:
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush
And I also tried to clear the ARP cache by:
ip -s -s neigh flush all

Is there another way to clear all active session, after the VPN is going down?